# Amazon ELB with SSL and nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have a question about SSL in EC2 with nodejs server.

I have an instance (ubuntu) linked to a domain where I deploy a nodejs app in port 3000, its working fine.

Now Im trying to redirect https (port 443) conections to port 3000 but Im doing something wrong

[image]

My security group

[image]

Im missing something ?

http://domain:3000/ping --> OK

https://domain/ping --> KO

Thanks

Comment: Does the HTTPS request time out, or get a certificate error, or some other error?

Comment: Also, do you have your domain name pointing correctly to the ELB, or do you have it pointing directly to the EC2 server?

Comment: @MarkB ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED 

Domain is pointed to ec2 public ip.

But no https requests are working, maybe should be pointed to elastic ip or to ELB (if it is possible) ?

Comment: Sorry your application domain is pointing to EC2 instance or the ELB?

Comment: No problem @PiyushPatil

Is pointed to EC2 instance public ip

Comment: And where did you add the SSL certificate? ELB or the EC2 Instance?

Comment: @PiyushPatil to ELB directly, I have just edit first message with the image and the certificate attached to rule

Comment: Ok so for your application to serve the SSL certificate from the ELB the domain of your application should point the ELB.

Comment: Not sure how you expect this to work with your domain pointing to the EC2 instance. You have to point the domain to the ELB in order to make use of the ELB. Right now you are completely bypassing the ELB.

Comment: @PiyushPatil and MarkB.

 Ready, it was the problem of course, I dont know what I was thinking

Thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please point you domain to AWS ELB as per your comments and the application will start serving HTTPS.

Comment: I cant not set this way, I get this message:

Load balancer protocol and instance protocol must be at the same layer.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I edited the answer please add that setting.